# Create custom validator for birthdate to check that the user is at majority age

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following piece of code in my model for which I would like to add a custom validator:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

I tried researching but there is no specific answer. I'd like to know the correct syntax for creating a custom validator for a date

Comment: HI, what have you tried to google?

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question, or a problem statement. And "how to" is a bit too vague. We will help you fix bugs or answer specific questions about your code, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Create a class and derive it from `ValidationAttribute` class and override `IsValid` method in it and then implement your validation logic inside the method:

```
public class AgeMajorityValidator : ValidationAttribute  
{  
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)  
    {  
        if (value != null)  
        {  
            DateTime dateOfBirth;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dateOfBirth))
                return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is not valid date format");

            int age = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dateOfBirth).Ticks).Year - 1;

            if (age > 18)
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            else
                return new ValidationResult("Please Enter a Valid Age.");
        }

        return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is required");
    }
```

2.Use `AgeMajorityValidator` as an attribute in your model like below:

```
[Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[AgeMajorityValidator]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```